# Files showing with yellow exclamation mark in solution explorer

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am starting a tutorial on .NET Core and I am following along and when I add certain types of files to the project (.css, .html).. they are in the solution explorer but then once I edit them and save I see this:

[image]

I don't see where I can include them in the project.  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding but still same issue.

I can reference the css file in the index.html file like so:

`<link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

but if I drag and drop the css file into the index.html file the link looks like this:

`<link href="wwwroot/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />` and I get blue lines under the href saying that path cannot be found.

Even my `Startup.cs` file is showing with exclamation mark.  This happens when I edit and save the file.

[image]

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually using VS 2015, as you've tagged your question, you need to upgrade to 2017. 2015 only has limited .NET Core support and even then, only supports 1.1 and below, which is frankly not worth developing on. Despite the major release versioning, 1.x was in no way ready for prime-time. Long and short, if you want to develop with Core, you need 2017.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Is there any documentation to support this?  Trying my best to convince my superiors to upgrade me to 2017.

Comment: I don't know of any specific documentation to that effect. All of the prerequisites and starter guides direct you to download 2017, but don't explicitly state that previous versions wouldn't work. However, Core 2.0 is completely incompatible with 2015, so it's easily verifiable simply by trying to create or load a 2.0 project in 2015. FWIW, the Community edition of VS is of course free, and for the most part perfectly sufficient for developing Core apps. You just don't get some niceties like live unit testing (which you may not have had anyways, based on your edition).

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!